# Data Mapper, only for CRUD operations?

Tags: php, oop, datamapper, dao

I have recently started reading about data mappers and all the articles I've found only demonstrate CRUD operations like:

```
$user = new User('John', 'Joe', 'john@hotmail.com');
$userMapper->insert($user);

// or this...
$user = $userMapper->fetchById(239);
```

Surely they are supposed to do more?

Currently in my application I use DAO's (or something similar anyway) so for example when I need a `$user` object one of my factories creates a `$userDAO` object and injects it into my `$user` object. And to do a query from my `$user` object I just do:

```
$this->userDAO->getNumActiveOrders($this->userId);
```

and it will do the query in the `$userDAO` object and return the result.

After loads of reading it seems my implementation is wrong because the domain object should not know about the DAO and vice versa. Am I right or wrong?

If it's wrong to do it that way then I assume that data mappers must be used for more than CRUD operations?

So if I wanted to find out how many active orders a user has I can do something like:

```
$userMapper->getNumActiveOrders($userId);
```

Would that be correct?

And if I wanted to set that value in my `$user` object I would have to do something like:

```
$user->setNumActiveOrders($userMapper->getNumActiveOrders($userId));
```

Using my implementation of DAO's seems to be a lot faster and uses less code than using data mappers but I am probably implementing data mappers wrongly.

Any advice would be great thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After loads of reading it seems my implementation is wrong because the domain object should not know about the DAO and vice versa. Am I right or wrong?

That is correct.

> If it's wrong to do it that way then I assume that data mappers must be used for more than CRUD operations?

The purpose of a [DataMapper is to map data from a Database to Domain Objects](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). Since object graphs are usually not structured like data in a relational database system, you need some sort of mapper to get the relational data from the database into your objects and vice versa. DataMappers try to solve the problem of [Impedance Mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).

> So if I wanted to find out how many active orders a user has I can do something like:

```
$userMapper->getNumActiveOrders($userId);
```

> Would that be correct?

Yes, you could it do it that way. But you could also query the user object for it, e.g.

```
echo $user->getActiveOrders();
```

and your user object would likely have some sort of [*Lazy Loading* mechanism](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) to fetch the Active Orders then.

> And if I wanted to set that value in my $user object I would have to do something like:

```
$user->setNumActiveOrders($userMapper->getNumActiveOrders($userId));
```

No. You'd simply set the Active Orders. The number can be derived from them. If the count is something you want inserted in the database, you'd handle that in the Mapper.

> Using my implementation of DAO's seems to be a lot faster and uses less code than using data mappers but I am probably implementing data mappers wrongly.

That's pretty much normal, because DAO's only query the database and don't do any mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's the word "Mapping" that gets me. No matter how many examples I see I still can't fully grasp it. Would using a Lazy Loading mechanism mean static/global calls? Since a DAO is for querying and a Mapper is for mapping does that mean they can be used together somehow? Like joining them as one object?

Comment: @user1925055 your DataMapper will know the DAO so it can load and persist from/to the database. As for Lazy Loading: no, you don't need statics and globals. A possible solution would be to create the User object with a placeholder object for Active Orders which will load the data from the database and replace itself with a Collection of mapped Active Orders. Follow the link I gave for more options.